# cannot open file in library Matrix

Tags: connection

Everyone,

R cannot open the connection.

https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/output/matrices

Thanks in advance for great help!

Best,

Yue

> library(Matrix)
>
> matrix_dir = "/opt/filtered_feature_bc_matrix/"
>
> barcode.path <- paste0(matrix_dir, "barcodes.tsv")
>
> features.path <- paste0(matrix_dir, "features.tsv")
>
> matrix_dir = "/opt/filtered_feature_bc_matrix/"
>
> mat <- readMM(file = matrix.path)

Error in open.connection(file) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file) :
cannot open file '/opt/filtered_feature_bc_matrix/matrix.mtx': No such file or directory>

Answer (score 0):

```html
> library(Matrix)
> matrix_dir = "/home/li/"
> barcode.path <- paste0(matrix_dir, "barcodes.tsv")
> features.path <- paste0(matrix_dir, "features.tsv")
> matrix.path <- paste0(matrix_dir, "matrix.mtx")
> mat <- readMM(file = matrix.path)
> feature.names = read.delim(features.path, 
+                            header = FALSE,
+                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> barcode.names = read.delim(barcode.path, 
+                            header = FALSE,
+                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> colnames(mat) = barcode.names$V1
> rownames(mat) = feature.names$V1
```